# df and hard links issue for backup

Tags: disk-usage, hard-link

We are doing incremental backup with use of hard links the initial size was 10 TB and we added 1 TB weekly .

backup1: 10TB
week2: 1TB
week3: 1TB

`du -hs week2` reports 11 TB; it is ok as inode are same and `du` considers it to create disk usage find with it ..

but when we do `df` to `/backup` (40TB) volume it is reporting backup1 (10T)+week2(11T)+week3(12T) = 33 TB --

this is bit critical as `df` suspects that volume is growing fast (which is not since it only adds 1TB per week) and we are getting alarms about space  ...

Is there any way we can tell `df` not to count hard links ? or any other command to find the exact free space in volume?

Answer (score 1):

The output from df is *correct*.  Apparently you are not getting any reduction in the size of backups with the tool you are using.

In your investigation, it may help to know that `du` will show the effect of hardlinks.  Run it on the directories together, in order, e.g. `du -shc backup1 week2 week3`.  It will show reduced size for the later directories if they contain hardlinks to previous ones, and the last line will show a total.  See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951883/du-counting-hardlinks-towards-filesize

This link also points out, if you want to examine the difference that accounting for hardlinks makes, compare the above with `du -l ...`.  This option is described as "count sizes many times if hard linked".

Comment: Than If hardlinks also take same extra space like original files.. than what is the benefit of them ? .. if there are 4 backups than what i noticed that total df shows 4X space ... where as it should report 1x since they all point to same inodes..

Comment: @Zeeshan please provide evidence that the backups are hardlinked :)

Comment: I used this http://rsnapshot.org/faq.html

Comment: @Zeeshan evidence please.  use `ls -l` or `stat` on unchanged file in both snapshots to show link count > 1